# Mobile Safari/WebKit memory issues

Tags: ios, ajax, html, xmlhttprequest, mobile-safari

We are writing an HTML 5 app that requires large files to be loaded.

We are loading binary data files via ajax. The app always crashes on iPad.

Upon further investigation with instruments on a MAC we noticed that while downloading the file, the memory allocated for webkit exponentially grows then runs out of memory. (100MB file grows memory over 550MB then browser crashes)

We tested loading all kinds of other types of files via other methods such as the Image obj as shown below.

```
function testImage() {
        var download = new Image();
        download.src = 'data/33MB.jpg?n=' + new Date().getTime();
    }
```

After the above 33MB image loads, Instruments show us that the memory has grown to 309 MB.

[image: Instruments panel]

And here is a sample XHR call with same results loading a large binary file.

```
function testXHR() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'data/100MB.bin?n=' + new Date().getTime());
    xhr.send();
}
```

We are baffled as to what is happening. 
How could we load large files on safari mobile?

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was wondering if you ended up finding anything about this? We're having an issue right now in our web app where downloading a simple 95MB zip file using a simple XMLHttpRequest crashes Safari on iOS 9.3.5. The download never completes, it crashes around 80% completion. We also suspect a memory issue but not sure. Thanks

Comment: We ended up moving on and bypassing the problem by reducing file sizes. So, no never found out anything more about it.

Comment: I see, thanks. Yesterday I also found out it was related to the specific iPad I was testing on. Later I tested on a newer iPhone and suddenly everything worked perfectly. So we just decided to move on as well and we'll just add a requirement for our users to have newer devices. For iOS at least, for Android there was no issue, even for older devices.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up information.